# ngZone or zone.js: the place of monkey-patching?

Tags: angular, zone.js, ngzone

I'm learning how **ngZone** works in **Angular**.
I understood that it's doing monkey-patching of standard async operations(such as setTimeout).

But who is doing monkey-patching? zone.js library or Angular itself within ngZone?
It would be great if you could show specific place in source code where it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs the zone within zone.js, and zone.js provides a scope with patched API.

You can yourself use `zone.run(...)` without anything from Angular and get all the effects of the patched API.

See also https://github.com/angular/zone.js/

The code that patches the timer 
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/common/timers.ts#L22

Comment: so setTimeoutOriginal !== setTimeout?
I could not find a specific place in zone.js, could you provide me a line?

Comment: @StepanSuvorov you can't get the original method after zone has loaded. That would be internal to zone as I've never seen an API to get the original.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini let assume I store the link to the original object and only after include zone.js

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you for the update, for some reason I still can't grep `setTimeout` string there. It's logical that if you overwrite the property you should write it down, no?

Comment: They seem to patch the Timer object, not each method individually.

Comment: yes, thank you very much, I found it - https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/browser/browser.ts#L30

Answer (score 1):

The zone library has to work in both the browser and server-side projects. So it's a little more complicated than just patching global functions.

Zone not only patches global APIs, but also patches event objects as they are broadcasted. The patching is done via `Zone.__load_patch` and you can see what is being patched in these modules.

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/browser/browser.ts

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/node/node.ts

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/rxjs/rxjs.ts

It's clearly not a simply process. I'm sure there are still some edge cases that zone hasn't patched.

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patching is done by Zone.js. In ng_zone.ts, zone.ts is loaded which creates the root zone as well as monkey patches the API.

NGZone simply forks a child zone named '[angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d4b8b2440673049c58d51b0ae4afceb028d62cc0/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L257)' and provides [callbacks](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d4b8b2440673049c58d51b0ae4afceb028d62cc0/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L260-L300) in zone specifications. In those callbacks, it [emits](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d4b8b2440673049c58d51b0ae4afceb028d62cc0/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L242) events which are further subscribed in application_ref.ts and change detection is kicked off.

Monkey Patching: This is done by calling [Zone.__load_patch()](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/browser/browser.ts#L28) function with 2 arguments. First argument is the identifier of the monkey-patched APIs and second is the patch function which when executed, [replaces](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/zone.ts#L687) the actual browser API with the re-defined version.

Now, this is just the tip of the iceberg. Actual magic is done by calling [patchMethod()](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/utils.ts#L337) of utils.ts. For set/clearTimeOut case, this is done [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/timers.ts#L62).

In patchMethod(), original api is saved in local variable i.e. [delegate](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/utils.ts#L353) and the same is returned which is saved in [setNative](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/1ba851989ccb6907df49bba37ee24ab60adf13a9/lib/common/timers.ts#L61) variable inside timers.ts.

For complete workflow, you can refer below article.

https://medium.com/reverse-engineering-angular/angular-deep-dive-zone-js-how-does-it-monkey-patches-various-apis-9cc1c7fcc321